# mime getType fails on valid mime-type

Tags: mime

I am using the mime npm package to extract mime types from file types, however some files already have a valid mime-type, in which case the function return null. Is there any way to have it return the mime-type regardless? For example, `mime.getType(file.type)` should return `application/pdf` when `file.type` is `pdf` **and** when it is `application/pdf`